# No Activity found to handle Intent while sending email

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am trying to send the picture clicked through my application as an attachment via email. The picture is clicked and I get the path correctly but the application throws me a run time exception.."No activity found to handle Intent". I am testing this on my device and I have my gmail account configured. I am not sure how to resolve this. Please help.

This is my code:

```
public static void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList, String title, String subject, String body) {

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,    Uri.parse("mailto:someone@example.com"));
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, capturedImageFilePath);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

And this is the log:

```
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=plain/text flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:852)
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904):     at com.example.attachmail.AttchmentActivity.sendEmail(AttchmentActivity.java:133)
01-15 11:26:04.455: E/AndroidRuntime(9904):     at com.example.attachmail.AttchmentActivity$2.onClick(AttchmentActivity.java:93)
```

Comment: Try adding the `Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION` flag. It might help you figure it out.

Comment: Tried Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION throws me the following exception:: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similier issue, I have pass the parameters fo a function which sends the email with an intent.
However I notice that the I needed to use the line intent.setData(Uri uri) and if the email parameter was just email then it needs to be with "mailto:" text
Example:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+email));
```

like here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+email));
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailContent);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
                try {

                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Email error:",e.toString());
                }
```

*If you are testing it on an emulator there might be a problem with "Sharing" apps not configured, so either make sure to set it on the emulator or test it on an actual device.*

Comment: This doesn't look like a solution to me, I still get the same errors.

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO ...`

Comment: Oh, I think I've found the error, the email app wasn't configured on this emulator. It works now!

Comment: Test it on a real device
I thought that might be the problem.

Comment: Calling setData() erases anything set prior to data or type just as an fyi

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to send email.

```
                   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                   sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(path));

                   sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"))
```

Comment: public static void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList, String title, String subject, String body) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("message/rfc822");
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, capturedImageFilePath);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email:"));
 }

Comment: the above code throws me this exception: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? I dont understand I have set that flag already.

Comment: just use startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:") in last line.

Comment: If I remove context. it throws me complier error:: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity. I think I should remove the code from the method and then try what you are suggesting.

Comment: Tryed removing from the method and using startActivity() without context..still the same exception. :(

Answer (score 1):

Changed Intent.ACTION_SENDTO to Intent.ACTION_SEND. I didnt want the other options of send like bluetooth and all thats why I wrote send to..but couldnt get it to work. So finally changed it to send and it works just fine now. No idea what exactly the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is because of the MIME type that you have set is "plain/text" and the FLAG that you have set i.e.FLAG ACTIVITY NEW TASK.

Here is something that can help you.
Try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860156/how-to-send-email-with-attachmentimage) link or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518055/image-attachment-to-a-mail-how-in-android) link.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailSignature);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toSenders);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectText);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageText+"\n\n"+emailSignature); 

        emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        File bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
            "/"+FOLDER_NAME+"/picture.jpg");
        myUri = Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
```

Comment: I changed the type to image/jpeg and removed the flag. But it throws me this exception: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? So I set the flag again and tried changing the content type only, now I am back to the old couldn't find Intent exception.

Comment: Try "text/plain" and let me know what happens :)

Comment: I tried that initially. Without the flag it throws me the context requires flag exception and with the flag it throws me couldn't find Intent exception. :( :(

Comment: see my updated answer.I have added one more link to it.Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from your code

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

& then try again.

Comment: Removing that flag throws me this exception: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?