# Android: sending an image by email through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

So far I've been able to send an image as an attachment but I would like to make it part of the email's body. I know in iOS it is possible to simply pass a link to the image in an  but this does not seem to work in Android.  I tried using this:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  Html.fromHtml(removeImgTags("<img.../>"));
```

But this only appends an object that is however not parsed as an image. I also tried the other version of this method:

```
Html.fromHtml(url, new MyImageGetter(), null)
```

And this had the same effect. So is this even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860156/how-to-send-email-with-attachmentimage

Comment: Thanks Rachel but did you actually read my question?

Comment: it seems to be the same problem

Comment: !"part of the email's body".equals("with Attachment");