# Image type issue in android

Tags: android, android-image

On button click, I want to attach an image from drawable and send an email(from chooser).
My button click works, email chooser opens. For example, Gmail opens and the image is attached. The problem is that the image doesn't have a proper extension. When the email is sent and the receiver downloads the attachment and renames it with `.jpg`. It perfectly works then. 
I have posted the code below.
I have added the project on GitHub.

The link is https://github.com/TheKushalBhagat/EmailButton.
You can download, work on it and please help me with the solution.

My code:
[image: Code]

Comment: try :  String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    mBitmap, "Image Description", null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);  convert drawable to bitmap and use it as intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457457/android-intent-send-an-email-with-image-attachment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860156/how-to-send-email-with-attachmentimage